# Heat maps using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to do this kind of plotting with matplotlib? Or somewhat close?

I know fill can be used but the block texture I am not sure of.

Thanks.

[image: ]]

Comment: This isn't a heatmap, the rectangles are proportional to the size of the object, in a heatmap the "size" correlates to the color. Incidentally it may be useful to know this comes from http://windirstat.info/.

Answer (score 1):

These types of plots are called **[Treemaps](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap/)**.

> A Treemap is a space-constrained visualization of hierarchical structures. It is very effective in showing attributes of leaf nodes using size and color coding. Treemap enables users to compare nodes and sub-trees even at varying depth in the tree, and help them spot patterns and exceptions.

They are recursively built, so posting a complete example would be difficult. A small  cookbook recipe for Treemaps using matplotlib can be found [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/TreeMap).

#### Related questions:

[Python graph like windirstat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872099/python-graph-like-windirstat)

[Treemap visualization in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282935/treemap-visualization-in-python)